# Adding introspection to TikZ/pgf shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

After digging into the output of `\tracingmacros=1` during a while, I'll ask here... I am trying to add a bit of introspection to `pgf` shapes. The idea is to be able to "extract" a `\savedmacro` of a shape.

To be more specific: is it possible to define the following `\whatamI` macro so that it expands to the shape (passed as argument) internal `\Iam`?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclareshape{myA}{
    \savedmacro{\Iam}{\edef\Iam{A}}
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    \behindbackgroundpath{
        \pgfnode{circle}{center}{\Iam}{}{\pgfusepath{stroke}}
    }
}
\pgfdeclareshape{myB}{
    \savedmacro{\Iam}{\edef\Iam{B}}
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    \behindbackgroundpath{
        \pgfnode{rectangle}{center}{\Iam}{}{\pgfusepath{stroke}}
    }
}
\def\whatamI#1{%
    % extract the saved macro \Iam definition
    % return \relax or -NoItem- or whatever if not defined in the shape
    % ???
}
\begin{document}
    They works: \begin{tikzpicture}
        % \tracingmacros=1
        \node [myA](A) at(0,0) {};
        % \tracingmacros=1
        \node [myB](B) at(1,0) {};
        % ...more code
        \edef\nodeAis{\whatamI{A}} % so now I can do different things dinamically
        \node [draw, rectangle,red,right] at (2,0) {%
            Node A is \nodeAis};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output from the MWE above]

Notice that I really do not need to retrieve the instance-specific `savedmacro` of a shape through its label/name. Even being able to retrieve the last one specified or to retrieve the value *in the shape text* would suffice to me.

Comment: Try `\def\whatamI#1{\csname pgf@sh@ma@#1\endcsname\message{^^J^^J I am \Iam^^J^^J}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the main problem is that you do not know where are the saved things.
For macros, they are in `\pgf@sh@ma@NAMEOFNODE` where `NAMEOFNODE` is to be replaced with the name of the node.

For instance, if I insert `\show\pgf@sh@ma@A` in your code, I get

> ```
> > \pgf@sh@ma@A=macro:
> ->\def \Iam {A}.
> ```

If, instead, I insert `\show\pgf@sh@ma@B`, I get

> ```
> > \pgf@sh@ma@B=macro:
> ->\def \Iam {B}.
> ```

There will be multiple things if there are more than one saved macros.
For example for the shape `regular polygon` from `shapes.geometric`, there are its saved macros

> ```
> > \pgf@sh@ma@NAMEOFPOLYGON=macro:
> ->\def \sides {5}\def \anglestep {72.0}\def \calculateradii {\def \radius {5.82619pt}\def \anchorradius {6.07338pt}}\def \startangle {90.0}.
> ```

Back to your question. To extract the `\Iam` of node `(A)`, just execute `\pgf@sh@ma@A` and then `\Iam` will be defined to be `A`. Similarly if you execute `\pgf@sh@ma@B` then `\Iam` will be defined to be `B`.

So the following works

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [myA](A) at(0,0) {};
    \node [myB](B) at(1,0) {};
    \node [draw, rectangle,red] at (3,0) {%
        Node A is \pgf@sh@ma@A\Iam};
    \node [draw, rectangle,green,right] at (5,0) {%
        Node B is \pgf@sh@ma@B\Iam};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

P.S. Here is a list

- `pgf@sh@ns@#1`: "node shape", such as `rectangle` or `circle`.
- `pgf@sh@np@#1`: saved anchors and dimensions.
- `pgf@sh@nt@#1`: transformation applied to the node; this affects the position of anchors so it is worth remembering.
- `pgf@sh@pi@#1`: the picture id; this is used for remember picture etc.
- `pgf@sh@ma@#1`: saved macros as in this answer.